# Parse a number but keep negative's

Tags: php, regex, numbers

I am trying to un-format a number to it's original form but keep whether or not it is negative. Someone on stack overflow led me to this code that work's very nicely but it does not keep the negative.

Could anyone help me get a better fix on this?

**EDIT** - For USD Currency/normal numbers

**Example:**

> 1,234 = 1234
>
> -1,234 = -1234
>
> 1,234.00 = 1234
>
> 1,234.56 = 1234.56

```
function numberUnformat($number)
{
   $cleanString = preg_replace('/([^0-9\.,])/i', '', $number);
   $onlyNumbersString = preg_replace('/([^0-9])/i', '', $number);

   $separatorsCountToBeErased = strlen($cleanString) - strlen($onlyNumbersString) - 1;

   $stringWithCommaOrDot = preg_replace('/([,\.])/', '', $cleanString, $separatorsCountToBeErased);
   $removedThousendSeparator = preg_replace('/(\.|,)(?=[0-9]{3,}$)/', '', $stringWithCommaOrDot);

   return (float) str_replace(',', '.', $removedThousendSeparator);
}
```

Comment: Does this need to support numbers in internationalized formats (i.e. `1.000,01`)?

Comment: no it doesn't, good question

Comment: "unformat" is better spelt "parse"

Comment: @bryan: That code you posted is trying to handle internationalization

Comment: Hopefully you are noting based on a few of the answers below that this is not a problem best solved with regular expressions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In case you have the ICU extension (which is bundled in PHP 5.3) available, try this:

```
$formatter = new NumberFormatter('en_US', NumberFormatter::DECIMAL);
echo $formatter->parse('-1,234.56');
```

Comment: Good usage of this extension.

Comment: This solution is much clearer than using regular expressions.

Answer (score 2):

Change your regular expression to match the negative numbers, too:

```
$cleanString = preg_replace('/([^\-0-9\.,])/i', '', $number);
```

Test cases:

```
echo numberUnformat('1,234')."\n";
echo numberUnformat('-1,234')."\n";
echo numberUnformat('1,234.00')."\n";
echo numberUnformat('1,234.56 ')."\n";
```

Output:

```
1234
-1234
1234
1234.56
```

[**Demo!**](https://eval.in/67242)

Comment: This work's very nicely except I have a DECIMAL (10,2) in MySQL which is keeping the .00 at the end. Anyway to parse that?

Comment: @bryan: Sorry, I don't understand? Could you please give me an example of string that this regex fails to replace?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to remove any extraneous minus signs in the middle of the string, too:

```
$cleanString = preg_replace('/[^0-9.,-]|(?<=.)-/', '', $number);
$onlyNumbersString = preg_replace('/[^0-9-]|(?<=.)-/', '', $number);
```

Note that you don't need the parentheses, backslash, or `/i` in your original.

Comment: Why are you using `(?<=.)` ? It will just prevent `-` that are at the beginning of the string to be replaced.

Comment: @HamZa - exactly.  We want to keep `-` at the beginning of the string, and remove them elsewhere.

Answer (score 2):

I would actually add some parameters to the function to allow specification of grouping and decimal separators (and possibly allow ability to cast to float or decimal and go to a solution like this:

```
function number_unformat($num_string, $group_sep = ',', $dec_sep = '.', $cast_to_type = true) {
    if (substr_count($num_string, $dec_sep) > 1) {
        // input was invalid
        throw new Exception('Inavlid string: `' . $num_string . '` passed to function. Too many decimal separators.');
    }   
    // remove grouping separator
    $string = str_replace($group_sep, '', $num_string);
    if (true === $cast_to_type) {
        // change any decimal separators to periods before casting
        $string = str_replace($dec_sep, '.', $string, $count);
        if ($count === 1) {
            return (float)$string;
        } else {
            return (int)$string;
        }
    } else {
        return $string;
    }
}
```

Note that there is no need at all to use regular expression here.

Comment: @bryan Thanks, though honestly if you are going to delve into internaltionaliation at all you might want to use the suggestion provided by Andreas Baumgart

Comment: Not really diving into internationalization, just want to be safe in case of typos.

Comment: For some reason this is not working on `$_POST` variables that don't have a decimal. I don't know why

Comment: @bryan Can you show your current usage along with any debugging results you may have?

Answer (score 0):

A fairly quick (though imperfect) fix would be to change the first two lines of the function:

```
$cleanString = preg_replace('/([^-0-9\.,])/i', '', $number);
$onlyNumbersString = preg_replace('/([^-0-9])/i', '', $number);
```

Though this will cause a problem if you have a number like 2-434.43.

Answer (score 0):

One could muck with the regular expressions to keep the negative, but to me it's simpler to do the following at the end:

```
$absvalue = (float) str_replace(',', '.', $removedThousendSeparator);
if ($number[0] == '-') {
    $absvalue = $absvalue * -1.0;
}
return $absvalue;
```

I might have a syntax error in there, my PHP is rusty, but the idea is just to check and see if the input string starts with a negative sign, and if it does, multiply the result by negative 1.