# How to disable decimal point conversion in php

Tags: php

when I submit `1,000,000`, it appears as `1`, but if I submit `1000000`, it appears as `1,000,000`. I want the output to be `1,000,000`, regardless of how it is submitted. Kindly help!

Here is the PHP code:

```
if(!function_exists('get_property_price')){
    function get_property_price(){
        global $post;
        $price_digits = doubleval(get_post_meta($post->ID, 'REAL_HOMES_property_price', true));
        if($price_digits){
            $currency = get_theme_currency();
            $price_post_fix = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'REAL_HOMES_property_price_postfix', true);
            $decimals = intval(get_option( 'theme_decimals'));
            $decimal_point = get_option( 'theme_dec_point' );
            $thousands_separator = get_option( 'theme_thousands_sep' );
            $currency_position = get_option( 'theme_currency_position' );
            $formatted_price = number_format($price_digits,$decimals, $decimal_point, $thousands_separator);
            if($currency_position == 'after'){
                return $formatted_price . $currency. ' ' . $price_post_fix;
            }else{
                return $currency . $formatted_price . ' ' . $price_post_fix;
            }
        }else{
            return __('NA','framework');
        }
    }
}

if(!function_exists('property_price')){
    function property_price(){
        echo get_property_price();
    }
}

if(!function_exists('get_custom_price')){
    function get_custom_price($amount){
        $amount = doubleval($amount);
        if($amount){
            $currency = get_theme_currency();
            $decimals = intval(get_option( 'theme_decimals'));
            $decimal_point = get_option( 'theme_dec_point' );
            $thousands_separator = get_option( 'theme_thousands_sep' );
            $currency_position = get_option( 'theme_currency_position' );
            $formatted_price = number_format($amount,$decimals, $decimal_point, $thousands_separator);
            if($currency_position == 'after'){
                return $formatted_price . $currency;
            }else{
                return $currency . $formatted_price;
            }
        }else{
            return __('NA','framework');}}}
```

Comment: You question is slightly wrong. PHP does not convert this values to decimals seperated values, your framework does. In your theme look for the options `theme_thousands_sep` and `theme_dec_point`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Parse a number but keep negative's](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19964723/parse-a-number-but-keep-negatives)

Comment: GuyT i have tried to disable them from the function.php bt no any changes

Comment: @WilsonTish I guess they are declared in a database. You can't just disable them.

Comment: @WilsonTish After some further investigation I think that your are working on the `Real Homes` team in WordPress? I guess that you can change this settings when you login in as admin.

Comment: @GuyT am using that theme the problem is that when i Try to change the setting under the theme option on pricing> decimal point nothing changes it just get messed up on displaying the pricing

Comment: Team is ofcourse theme :') @WilsonTish How does it look when you change the option and it what do you change it?

Comment: @GuyT i change the price format> number of decimal place i set it to 0 >decimal point separator av set to none if i submit price eg 300,000 on the front view it displays 3 here is the website www.shambas.co.ke

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is simple to understand.

The doubleval function casts ("converts") values to floating point numbers.

For instance, the string '1000.55' would be converted to a floating point representing a number approximate to 1000.55. But the string '1,000.55' would be converted to 1, because 1,000.55 is not a valid floating point representation. The commas do not exist in PHP floating points representations, thus the string is truncated before being converted to a floating poing.

I believe the function that I implemented can solve your problem like this:

```
function formattedprice2float($formatted_price) {
    $decimal_point       = get_option('theme_dec_point');
    $thousands_separator = get_option('theme_thousands_sep');

    $price_string = str_replace(array($decimal_point, $thousands_separator),
                                array('.', ''),
                                $formatted_price);
    return is_numeric($price_string) ? (float)$price_string : null;
}

if(!function_exists('get_property_price')){
    function get_property_price(){
        global $post;
        $price_digits = formattedprice2float(get_post_meta($post->ID, 'REAL_HOMES_property_price', true));
        if($price_digits){
            $currency = get_theme_currency();
            $price_post_fix = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'REAL_HOMES_property_price_postfix', true);
            $decimals = intval(get_option( 'theme_decimals'));
            $decimal_point = get_option( 'theme_dec_point' );
            $thousands_separator = get_option( 'theme_thousands_sep' );
            $currency_position = get_option( 'theme_currency_position' );
            $formatted_price = number_format($price_digits,$decimals, $decimal_point, $thousands_separator);

            if($currency_position == 'after'){
                return $formatted_price . $currency. ' ' . $price_post_fix;
            }else{
                return $currency . $formatted_price . ' ' . $price_post_fix;
            }
        }else{
            return __('NA','framework');
        }
    }
}
```

I'm assuming that `get_post_meta($post->ID, 'REAL_HOMES_property_price', true)` is returning something like '1,000,000'.
I can't test it, because I don't have all the required files, but give it a try.

Comment: Hi Pedro.
Thanks very much it worked as magic. I really appreciate so much for your time and assistance, Continue with the same spirit! :)

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at `numfmt_parse`. Lots more info here: http://php.net/manual/en/numberformatter.parse.php

Here is the example from the PHP docs:

```
<?php
$fmt = numfmt_create( 'de_DE', NumberFormatter::DECIMAL );
$num = "1.234.567,891";
echo numfmt_parse($fmt, $num)."\n";
echo numfmt_parse($fmt, $num, NumberFormatter::TYPE_INT32)."\n";
?>
```

And the expected result:

```
1234567.891
1234567
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the line that formats the numbers:

```
$formatted_price = number_format($price_digits,$decimals, $decimal_point, $thousands_separator);
```

And those are the lines to set the separators (**.** and **,**):

```
$decimal_point = get_option( 'theme_dec_point' );
$thousands_separator = get_option( 'theme_thousands_sep' );
```

You can try to revert to a float with this code:

```
<?php
function get_option($propertyName) {
    static $properties = array('theme_dec_point' => '.',
                               'theme_thousands_sep' => ',');
    return $properties[$propertyName];
}

function formattedprice2float($formatted_price) {
    $decimal_point = get_option('theme_dec_point');
    $thousands_separator = get_option('theme_thousands_sep');

    $price_string = str_replace(array($decimal_point, $thousands_separator),
                                array('.', ''),
                                $formatted_price);
    return is_numeric($price_string) ? (float)$price_string : null;
}

// test
var_dump( formattedprice2float(number_format(100000, 2)) );
```

But it assumes that the options aren't changed and, of course, won't recover lost digits after the decimal mark. If the first assumption abviously fails, the price will be null.

Comment: Thanks Pedro but the code is giving this erro "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected $end i"

Comment: Hi, Wilson.  The last line wasn't tested and I added an uninitialized variable, but I believe the error wasn't related to that (it means that there's an extra or missing delimiter: {, or ), or ", or ', etc.). I edited the answer with a test. Test it as standalone file and copy the function "formattedprice2float" and use it. Regards.

Comment: Hi Pedro i tried again to edit the file using your codes am not sure if am doing the right thing or not. is there any way i can sent you the php file kindly

Comment: I don't know how to send private messages here (and if the feature exists). You can message me your email address through facebook (if you have an account) and I'll reply.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the character before you process the price with `str_replace()`

Your is going to look like this afterwards if you want to remove the comma:

```
$price_digits = doubleval(str_replace(',', '', get_post_meta($post->ID, 'REAL_HOMES_property_price', true));
```

Comment: Victor thanks for the help but the str_replace() results to an error on the website. Is there any other way

Comment: There was a typo in my code. I have changed this now